# Angular приложение не отвечает без редактирования кода

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

Создаю приложение на angular с использованием asp.net core, столкнулся с проблемой:

1. При запуске приложения запрос в `index.html` выдает `cannot GET /`
2. Если изменить код на фронте во время исполнения, то приложение работает в нормальном режиме
3. Абсолютно не важно, какой это код, я пробовал убрать вообще все модули, компоненты и зависимости и оставить только один `AppModule` со встроенными `BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule`, у которого компонент возвращал `<p>Надпись</p>`, и все также при запуске приложение не отвечало.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а откуда взялся обратный слэш? его там быть не должно.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Спасибо, что заметили, это опечатка

Comment: Возможно проблема с тем, что нужно сперва сбилдить фронт, скорее всего вы делаете это через ng serve, после того, как только закончится первая сборка, можно запустить бэк. Очень похоже, что у вас бэк пытается отдать фронт до того, как он будет готов.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin возможно, но до этого подобный же код запускался без проблем, все началось на том этапе, когда я распределял компоненты и связанные с ними скрипты по отдельным каталогам. У меня кроме корневого модуля есть еще 3 дочерних, и когда я подключил импорты после перемещения у первых двух,, все было в порядке, и проблема появилась как раз после того, как я попытался подключить третий модуль. При этом она осталась и после того, как я убрал вообще ссылки на него.